# Multi property check ternary operator on json object not working in nodejs while its working in google chrome console

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-console

I have a json object like below

```
let obj = { 'key1' : 'value1' , 'key2 : { 'key2a' : 'value2a' } }
```

I wanted to do a ternary operator check which is equivalent to below code

```
if(obj) {
  if(obj.key2) { 
    if(obj.key2.key2a) {
        return obj.key2a;
    }
  }
}
```

So, In google chrome console i have tried below to achieve it in simpler way and it worked...

```
obj?.key2?.key2a? obj.key2.key2a : '0'
```

[image]

If i am trying it in nodejs@12 its giving me syntax error. 
[image]

Can someone please help me understand this discrepancy ?

Comment: `if(obj.key2) { 
    if(obj.key2a) {` <-- that ain't right, should be `obj.key2.key2a`

Comment: It's an object. Nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: And you need Node 14 to use the `?.` operator.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a simple typo.
You are checking this way

```
if(obj) {
  if(obj.key2) {  // <- obj.key2 here
    if(obj.key2a) { // <- but checking another property on the same level too
        return obj.key2a;
    }
  }
}
```

I think you mean

```
if(obj) {
  if(obj.key2) {  // <- obj.key2 here
    if(obj.key2.key2a) { // <- now safely access child property here
        return obj.key2.key2a;
    }
  }
}
```

or shorter

```
if (obj && obj.key2 && obj.key2.key2a) {
  // ...
}
```

or

```
var result = obj && obj.key2 && obj.key2.key2a || "0";
```

Comment: Thanks @user2953241